# Simple definition of genus

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Although I use only the Weierstraß form of elliptic curves I want to introduce the official definition:

An elliptic curve over $k$ is a nonsingular curve over $k$ of genus 1 with a rational point defined over $k$.

But for this reason I need to give a definition of genus; Is there a simple way to define it for curves/elliptic curves?
To be honest I'm not even sure if I understood the regular definition of it, so I'd be happy if someone can suggest me an easy way to define it or explain me the original definition of it.

Many thanks

Comment: elliptic curves, are **abstract varieties** of dimension 1 and genus 1 indeed. Hartshorne's book is a good reference to sort out your question.

Comment: Also there are several definitions for genus in that context, which one do you know?

Comment: I only know the formal definition of genus - I just received an email from my professor that he wants the formal definition to be included; That's why I started checking the definitions of genus right now

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez the asker and answerer are both either deleted and there are no votes on any part of this. I've marked it as a duplicate to prevent any more bumps.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of genus has several equivalent definitions. Through algebraic geometry has many generalizations that you're probably not interested in. Genus, is something that you can intuitively understand in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where the 2-dimensional manifolds (i.e. surfaces )do exist. That is, the number of holes such a surface has, for instance for a torus the genus is $g=1$, connected sum of two tori is $g=2$, so on so forth. Apparently you can have genus zero (2-dimensional sphere is such an instance), where no holes whatsoever show up. Because elliptic curves are complex manifolds of dimension one (complex dimension), that means that have dimension 2 over $\mathbb{R}$ (keep in my mind, we always talk about non-singular objects) and we can transfer this intuitive definition to a non-singular curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Now, since you already know that they have genus 1, that means its *real* analogue must be what we call torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Indeed that's certainly true since you can prove that for an elliptic curve $E$, there is an isomoprhism of the form $E \cong \mathbb{C}/{\Lambda}$, where $\Lambda$ a lattice in the complex numbers. I haven't done a thorough explantion for any of the above, because the usual problem is when an OP asks something no one has idea of their background and that creates problems (the latter comment is just in case @Rene Schipperus intimidate you :P). I did all the above introduction to give maybe some intuition behind the formal definition that you already know (btw *in that context* the *formal* definition I mean is this one  described here in section orientable surfaces https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics) and I believe is quite tangible).

The above maybe are not enough, or too many to answer clearly your question because I don't know your background in algebraic/differential geometry. Though, as I have already mentioned above in comments, in case you understand what Hartshorne's book mean by abstract variety there is plenty of information in there to help you out.

For any possible questions do let me know.

Comment: Maybe you should send a copy to his professor. To see if he happy with your work.

Comment: Rene, in some way you are really entertaining... :-) @mayer_vietoris: The intuitive meaning as the number of holes is something I already knew but since an elliptic curve is just a curve I didn't know how to adapt with it...  I will now try to read your answer a couple of times, google some terms and hopefully I will understand it after that... Anyway, thank you so much for explaining :-)

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I honestly didn't mean something  offensive. I'm sorry if you get it like this. And into a certain extend I agree with what you said earlier... **J.Doe** great, that was the idea of writing out the above answer find out the sources and understand them, I believe theory behind elliptic curves is amazing and quite fruitful. If you need something (and I can help you) feel free.

Comment: I am not offended, my opinion was clearly stated in my previous comments, (now deleted, by whom ?), I don't feel I need to elaborate.